# CharacterVariant in fontspec package

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ebgaramond

According to the documentation for the `fontspec` package, this code:

```
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic} very \\
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[CharacterVariant=5] very \\
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[CharacterVariant=5:0] very \\
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[CharacterVariant=5:1] very \\
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[CharacterVariant=5:2] very \\
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[CharacterVariant=5:3] very
```

Should produce this output:

[image]

And, indeed, this works very nicely for me using XeLaTeX on Linux.

But when I run `xelatex` on the file, I get a lot of complaints like this:

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'CharacterVariant=5' (+cv05) not available for font 'EB
* Garamond 12 Italic/I' with script 'Latin' and language 'Default'.
*************************************************
```

(And similarly for the other CharacterVariants.)

What does this error mean? As I said, the output appears to be OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\fontspec` tries to setup also the italic (and the bold) versions of the fonts. With `xelatex` the regular version of the font is found as "italic" and as the regular version doesn't have the character variants you get warnings (not errors):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

{\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic} very \textit{very}}

{\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[CharacterVariant=5:2] very \textit{very}}

{\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Regular} very \textit{very}}

{\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Regular}[CharacterVariant=5:2] very \textit{very}}

\end{document}
```

### Output with xelatex

[image]

You can suppress the warnings by loading the font e.g. as

```
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Italic}[
     CharacterVariant=5:2,
     ItalicFont={EB Garamond 12 Italic},
     BoldItalicFont={EB Garamond 12 Italic}]
```